# Ignore element position or put one element over the existed in MusixTex

Tags: musixtex

I have decided to convert all my music sheets from analog paper to digital usign MusixTeX. 
In musixtex there is no barre long line with number, so i created it myself, but after it distance between adjacent notes increased (see image in attachment).[image]

And the beam does not reach the end. On the image there is two part of code: first with my barre and second without. I thought may be there is some method for ignoring position my element or may be method for put my element over the current. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,inner=1.7cm,outer=1.5cm,top=0.4cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
%%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}


\title{\vspace*{-0.2cm}Bourr\'ee}
%%\fulltitle{Lute Suite in E Minor}
\date{}
\nobarnumbers

\newcommand{\barremy}[1]{$\stackrel{\text{#1}}{\scalebox{0.8}{\Large \Bigg \lfloor}}$}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \normalmusicsize
    \begin{flushright}
        J.\,S. Bach\\
        (1685--1750)
    \end{flushright}
    \hspace*{0.9cm}\textbf{Moderato}

    \begin{music}
        % 1 instruments
        \instrumentnumber{1}

        % instrument1(enbas) :2 portées
        \setstaffs1{1}

        % clefdefa(6)en1,clefdesol(0)en2
        \setclef1{0}
        \setbassclefsymbol1\bassoct
        \settrebleclefsymbol1\treblelowoct

        \generalsignature{+1}%
        %\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}
        \generalmeter{\allabreve}
        \def\qpl{\raise3\Interligne\soupir}

        %\nostartrule
        \parindent0pt
        \startpiece
        \addspace\afterruleskip
        \Notes \Ibu1Zi2\qb1{Zdf}\barremy{II}\tqh1i \en \bar
        \Notes \Ibu1Zi2\qb1{Zdf}\tqh1i \en \bar
        \leftrightrepeat
        \endpiece
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Just applied negative hspace

```
\newcommand{\barreline}[1]{\hspace{-8.83pt}$\stackrel{\text{\scriptsize{#1}}}{\scalebox{0.8}{\Large \Bigg \lfloor}}$}
```

And got the result:
[image]